# How to train sequential model with multiple images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

I am getting an error when passing in multiple images to train. But it is fine when passing just one image. The images are of the same size.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, datasets, models

# Load the template image
template_image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img('Template.jpg')
template_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(template_image)

# Load the actual image
actual_image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img('Actual.jpg')
actual_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(actual_image)

# Create a model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(template_array.shape)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
  layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'),
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.output_shape)

template_array = template_array.reshape((1, 549, 549, 3))
actual_array = actual_array.reshape((1, 549, 549, 3))
train_x = [template_array, actual_array]
y_train = np.array([1,0])
y_train = y_train.reshape(1,2)
train_y = [y_train, y_train]

print("X shape is: ")
print(template_array.shape)
print("Y shape is: ")
print(y_train)

# Train the model
model.fit(x=train_x, y=train_y, epochs=10)

# Make predictions
predictions = model.predict([actual_array])

# Check for incorrect or missing parts
for i in range(len(predictions)):
  if predictions[i][0] > predictions[i][1]:
    print('Part {} is missing or incorrect'.format(i))
```

Error received:

```
ValueError: Layer "sequential_28" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: 
[<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 549, 549, 3) dtype=float32>, 
<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, 549, 549, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

If I were to pass x=template_array and y = y_train it runs fine. But that means I trained off of only one image.

Am I not able to make an array of my images and a corresponding array of classification to pass all at once? How do I go about passing in all of my train data at once?

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: Actually the problem is that you have to concatenate both of your images, putting them in a list is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are passing two inputs to your model, not two samples. If you want to enter two samples, your train_x must have the shape [2, 549, 549, 3].
To accomplish this, you need to concatenate template_array and actual_array from their first axis.

`train_x = np.concatenate([template_array, actual_array], axis=0)`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that the first element (2 in the example you gave me) represented the batch size. [batches, height, width, channels]. Thus, I need to have z batches if I want to pass z number of samples.

Comment: Yes, the first dimension of the input is always the batch size.